# Saving a 32 bit RGBA buffer into a .png file (Cocoa OSX)

Tags: cocoa, macos, buffer, cocotron

I need to save the contents of a pixel editor application into a .png file but I am having trouble finding the best way to accomplish this.  The pixel data is stored in a 32 bit RGBA buffer.  Can anyone suggest any good tools I could use to accomplish this?

EDIT:
Unfortunately, CGImage and representationUsingType: are not supported by cocotron and I need to be able to target my app for PC release as well, can anyone suggest a third way of accomplishing this task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSBitmapImageRep` should get you what you need.  Load the data up into the `NSBitmapImageRep`
and then use `representationUsingType:properties:` to get it out as a PNG.  A quick example:

```
NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = 
    [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithBitmapDataPlanes:imageBuffer
                                            pixelsWide:imageWidth
                                            pixelsHigh:imageHeight
                                         bitsPerSample:8
                                       samplesPerPixel:4
                                              hasAlpha:YES
                                              isPlanar:NO
                                        colorSpaceName:NSDeviceRGBColorSpace
                                          bitmapFormat:NSAlphaFirstBitmapFormat
                                           bytesPerRow:imageWidth * 4
                                          bitsPerPixel:32];
NSData *pngData = [imageRep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType 
                                         properties:propertyDictionary];
```

If you can't use these Cocoa methods, check out [`libpng`](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/pngcode.html).

Comment: This worked great but unfortunatley the method representationUsingType: is not supported by cocotron, and I need to be able to target cocotron as well.  Can you suggest any other ways to accomplish this?

Comment: @Michael, edited answer to include a C library that will help you out.

Answer (score 2):

Create a [CGImage](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/) from the pixel data and feed it to a [CGImageDestination](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageDestination/).

Don't forget to [finalize the destination](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageDestination/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageDestinationFinalize) before releasing it. That step is mandatory, and very easy to forget.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it seems that CGImageCreate is not supported by clozure (this is a common lisp - cocoa bridge) can you suggest any other alternatives to your method and the one listed above.  Thanks for all your help!