# CoreGraphics: Encode RGBA data to PNG

Tags: c, image, core-graphics, core-foundation

I am trying to use the C interface of CoreGraphics & CoreFoundation to save a buffer of 32-bit RGBA data (as a void*) to a PNG file.  When I try to finialize the `CGImageDestinationRef`, the following error message is printed to the console:

`libpng error: No IDATs written into file`

As far as I can tell, the `CGImageRef` I'm adding to the `CGImageDestinationRef` is valid.

Relavent Code:

```
void saveImage(const char* szImage, void* data, size_t dataSize, size_t width, size_t height)
{
    CFStringRef name = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, szImage, kCFStringEncodingASCII);
    CFURLRef texture_url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(
                                                     NULL,
                                                     name,
                                                     kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle,
                                                     false);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data, dataSize, NULL);
    CGImageRef image = CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, 32 * width, colorSpace,
                                 kCGImageAlphaLast | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault, dataProvider,
                                 NULL, FALSE, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    // From Image I/O Programming Guide, "Working with Image Destinations"
    float compression = 1.0; // Lossless compression if available.
    int orientation = 4; // Origin is at bottom, left.
    CFStringRef myKeys[3];
    CFTypeRef   myValues[3];
    CFDictionaryRef myOptions = NULL;
    myKeys[0] = kCGImagePropertyOrientation;
    myValues[0] = CFNumberCreate(NULL, kCFNumberIntType, &orientation);
    myKeys[1] = kCGImagePropertyHasAlpha;
    myValues[1] = kCFBooleanTrue;
    myKeys[2] = kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality;
    myValues[2] = CFNumberCreate(NULL, kCFNumberFloatType, &compression);
    myOptions = CFDictionaryCreate( NULL, (const void **)myKeys, (const void **)myValues, 3,
                               &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

    CFStringRef type = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, "public.png", kCFStringEncodingASCII);
    CGImageDestinationRef dest = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(texture_url, type, 1, myOptions);

    CGImageDestinationAddImage(dest, image, NULL);

    if (!CGImageDestinationFinalize(dest))
    {
        // ERROR!
    }

    CFRelease(image);
    CFRelease(colorSpace);
    CFRelease(dataProvider);
    CFRelease(dest);
    CFRelease(texture_url);
}
```

This post is similar, except I'm not using the Objective C interface:  [Saving a 32 bit RGBA buffer into a .png file (Cocoa OSX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277418/saving-a-32-bit-rgba-buffer-into-a-png-file-cocoa-osx)

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous issues with your code.

Here it is rewritten how I would do it:

```
void saveImage(const char* szImage, void* data, size_t dataSize, size_t width, size_t height)
{
    CFStringRef name = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, szImage, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    CFURLRef texture_url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(
                                                     NULL,
                                                     name,
                                                     kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle,
                                                     false);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data,
                                                                dataSize, NULL);
    CGImageRef image = CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, 32 * width, colorSpace,
                                 kCGImageAlphaLast | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,
                          dataProvider, NULL, FALSE, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    // From Image I/O Programming Guide, "Working with Image Destinations"
    float compression = 1.0; // Lossless compression if available.
    int orientation = 4; // Origin is at bottom, left.
    CFStringRef myKeys[3];
    CFTypeRef   myValues[3];
    CFDictionaryRef myOptions = NULL;
    myKeys[0] = kCGImagePropertyOrientation;
    myValues[0] = CFNumberCreate(NULL, kCFNumberIntType, &orientation);
    myKeys[1] = kCGImagePropertyHasAlpha;
    myValues[1] = kCFBooleanTrue;
    myKeys[2] = kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality;
    myValues[2] = CFNumberCreate(NULL, kCFNumberFloatType, &compression);
    myOptions = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, (const void **)myKeys,
                    (const void **)myValues, 3, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                          &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

    CGImageDestinationRef dest = 
          CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(texture_url, kUTTypePNG, 1, NULL);

    CGImageDestinationAddImage(dest, image, NULL);
    CGImageDestinationSetProperties(dest, myOptions);

    if (!CGImageDestinationFinalize(dest))
    {
        // ERROR!
    }

}
```

First, never use ASCII when dealing with file system paths, use UTF8. Second, you were constructing a dictionary to be used to set the properties of the image, but you were using it with the wrong function. The documentation for [`CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageDestination/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL) says the following:

> **CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL**
>
> Creates an image destination that writes to a location specified by a
>   URL.
>
> ```
> CGImageDestinationRef CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL (
>    CFURLRef url,
>    CFStringRef type,
>    size_t count,
>    CFDictionaryRef options
> );
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>   *options* - Reserved for future use. Pass `NULL`.

You were trying to pass a dictionary of properties when you were supposed to pass `NULL`. (Also, you can simply use the `kUTTypePNG` Uniform Type Identifier string constant instead of re-creating it). First call `CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL()`, then call `CGImageDestinationAddImage()` to add the image, then call `CGImageDestinationSetProperties()` and pass in the dictionary of properties you created.

[UPDATE]: If after these changes you're still having `libpng error: No IDATs written into file` issues, try the following: First, make sure that `dataProvider` is non-`NULL`-- in other words, make sure the `CGDataProviderCreateWithData()` function succeeded. Second, if `dataProvider` is valid, perhaps try changing the options from `kCGImageAlphaLast | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault` to simply `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast` and see if it succeeds.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  I am still searching for this UTCoreTypes.h file that has the kUTTypePNG constant defined.  The documentation says it's in MobileCoreServices.framework, but I do not have that framework in my MacOSX10.8 SDK.  The underlying issue still exists, though: I still get `libpng error: No IDATs written into file` after applying your fixes for the options dictionary.

Comment: @Chris: MobileCoreServices is for iOS, which doesn't really have a full blown CoreServices framework like OS X does. In OS X, UTCoreTypes.h will be part of the `LaunchServices.framework`, which is a subframework of the `CoreServices.framework` umbrella framework. Updated the answer as well (or will shortly).

Comment: Ugh, didn't see your own answer before writing mine.

Comment: Using `UTF8String` for file system paths isn't a good idea, especially if it has non-ASCII text. Instead, you should use `fileSystemRepresentation` to get the proper path to send to POSIX file commands.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own questions:

1. In addition to the issues pointed out by NSGod, the IDAT issue was an invalid parameter to CGImageCreate(): parameter 5 is bytesPerRow, not bitsPerRow.  So `32 * width` was incorrect; `4 * width` is correct.
2. Despite what [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MobileCoreServices/Reference/UTTypeRef/Reference/reference.html) of the official documentation lists, UTCoreTypes.h is located in the `CoreServices.framework` for MacOSX, not `MobileCoreServices.framework`.